# How set culture for dataGrid validation (silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, culture

I need US culture. How do this?

[image]

Comment: This question is a little cryptic.  You've circled some text, its unclear what have a "US Culture" would do to change this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

You might also checkout the [following article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838238%28VS.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Its not very clearly what it is you are actually asking but this little bit of info might help.

The Thread `CurrentCulture` or `CurrentUICulture` doesn't always impact how elements created in Xaml behave.  To do that you need to set the `Language` property of the `UserControl`.  In the constructor before you call `InitialiseComponent` include:-

```
 Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("en-US");
```